# Is it correct to use "a news" in the given statement?

Tags: word-usage, verb-agreement

We generally don't use "a" or "an" before the word "news". However, I have suspicions about the following sentence.

Is it correct to say *"What sad news for us"* or do we need to use an "a" and say it like *"What **a** sad news for us"*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I am not a native english speaker, in my knowledge, you are using grammatically wrong sentence while speaking "a" with the noun "news". News is one of those nouns which seem plural but take singular verb with them. This type of noun is called "Mass nouns".

I suggest you could say:
***I have got a piece of news*** or ***I have got some news*** instead of saying ***I have a news.***

Comment: Yes. "News" is a mass noun - just like "water" or "air". It will take the definite article but not the indefinite.